Extract credible/confidence interval of a threshold in a Bayesian posterior draws distribution
I have a Bayesian model created through bayer package in R on which I need to calculate confidence/credible intervals for a specific posterior log-risk threshold.
After fitting the brm model I know I can assess the "risk" associated with a specific categorical variable in the model through an analysis of the number of posterior log-risk draws for that specific factor higher than 0 (in the example below: 7969/8000 = 99.61%).
How can I calculate a confidence/credible interval for that percentage?
Here reproducible code:
devtools::install_github("cccnrc/bayer")

library(bayer)

### import the built-in dataset mtcars
mtcars <- datasets::mtcars

### specify the treatment variable and the covariates you want to analyze
model_logistic <- bayer_logistic(
                      data = mtcars,
                      outcome = 'am',
                      covariates = c( 'mpg', 'cyl', 'vs', 'carb' ),
                      brm_max_treedepth = 15
                    )

posterior <- extract_posterior( model_logistic, var = 'mpg' )

posterior$b_mpg$risk_plot


### to manually get the percentage use posterior draws data:
length(which(posterior$b_mpg$data$b_mpg > 0)) / length(posterior$b_mpg$data$b_mpg)


Your posterior belief for the b_mpg variable is that is 99.61 percent likely to be higher than 0. There is no confidence interval for that number, this is the posterior.
A 95% credible interval for the b_mpg variable would be some interval that contains 95% of the posterior draws, so something like [0, 2] judging by your graph. There are multiple possibilities here, [0.01, 2.02] could be another 95% credible interval. You can use a package for calculating this interval, for example, https://easystats.github.io/bayestestR/articles/credible_interval.html.
